# unable to find lead ID in meta

Tags: facebook, integration, crm

I'm trying to send a CRM event, I made it to this point:
[image]

I have all the other details except the lead_id and I'm not able to figure out how do i get this lead ID, i went through the docs as well and did the setups as it asked me to but since this is my first time doing a manual CRM integration, I feel like I'm missing out a big step in between because without the lead ID, i don't think I can move ahead. Can anyone guide me on this?